# docutils: get line number for nested nodes

Tags: python, docutils

When parsing a ReStructuredText snippet with `docutils` and walking the document node tree, most nodes don't supply their line number in the source text. Example:

```
import io
from pathlib import Path
import docutils.frontend
import docutils.nodes
import docutils.parsers.rst


text = '''
Fizz
====

Lorem ipsum

Buzz
****

Lorem ``ipsum``

.. code-block:: python

   x = 0

.. note::

   Dolor sit amet

   .. code-block:: python

      y = 1
'''


class MyVisitor(docutils.nodes.GenericNodeVisitor):
    def default_visit(self, node):
        print('node: {:>15}, line: {}'.format(type(node).__name__, node.line))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    default_settings = docutils.frontend.OptionParser(components=(docutils.parsers.rst.Parser,)).get_default_values()
    document = docutils.utils.new_document('mydocs', default_settings)
    parser = docutils.parsers.rst.Parser()
    parser.parse(io.StringIO(text).read(), document)
    visitor = MyVisitor(document)
    document.walk(visitor)
```

Running this code yields:

```
node:        document, line: None
node:         section, line: 3
node:           title, line: 3
node:            Text, line: None
node:       paragraph, line: 5
node:            Text, line: None
node:         section, line: 8
node:           title, line: 8
node:            Text, line: None
node:       paragraph, line: 10
node:            Text, line: None
node:         literal, line: None
node:            Text, line: None
node:   literal_block, line: 15
node:          inline, line: None
node:            Text, line: None
node:            Text, line: None
node:          inline, line: None
node:            Text, line: None
node:            Text, line: None
node:          inline, line: None
node:            Text, line: None
node:            note, line: None
node:       paragraph, line: 18
node:            Text, line: None
node:   literal_block, line: None
node:          inline, line: None
node:            Text, line: None
node:            Text, line: None
node:          inline, line: None
node:            Text, line: None
node:            Text, line: None
node:          inline, line: None
node:            Text, line: None
```

Looks like none of the nested nodes gets the line number recorded. Is it possible to access this information in the custom node visitor impl? I didn't expect all nodes (like separate word nodes) to provide line numbers, but neither `note` nor the nested `code-block` in the example snippet do.

Comment: For inline nodes, `node.parent.line` or `node.parent.parent.line` should give the start line of the containing block level element. Block level elements missing line info can be reported to the related [Docutils feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/feature-requests/41/) page.